# R output data frame from function using within()

Tags: r, function, vector, output

I have two functions that imitate the function I have created.  The only difference is the last line.  The first returns a vector, the second a data frame; I want a data frame.  I do not understand the difference between the two.

```
x<-rnorm(5)
y<-rnorm(5)

t<-function(x,y){
d<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))
d$e<-y*2 
}

g<-t(x,y)

> g
[1] -1.3912452  1.0013463 -2.8913569  1.9724236 -0.3014467
```

This returns a vector

```
u<-function(x,y){
  d<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))
  within(d,e<-y*2) 
}


h<-u(x,y)
> h
            x          y          e
1  0.80599999 -0.6956226 -1.3912452
2 -0.04446587  0.5006731  1.0013463
3  0.65049716 -1.4456785 -2.8913569
4 -1.69269074  0.9862118  1.9724236
5  1.70878627 -0.1507234 -0.3014467
```

This returns a data frame.

I can run the first line by line, not as a function, and it returns a data frame, but not when I wrap it within the function.  Thank you for any insight.

Comment: In the first function you are returning `d$e` which is a vector, while in the second it is the `within` line, which returns data.frame

Comment: ok, I went back and added a final line which would be `d` in my above example and it returned a data frame.  I am new to functions, but this actually cleared up a lot about how to end my functions.

Comment: Also, you don't need `data.frame(cbind(..`,  Just `data.frame(x,y)` would be sufficient.  This matters when you have mixed class columns.

Comment: PLEASE... do not redefine t(). It is a perfectly useful R function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your first function returns a vector is that it is returning d$e, since that's the object created in the last line of your function.  If you add return(d) at the end of the function, you'll get the data frame you were expecting.  An explicit return is often a good idea.